# Converting values from array in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

In my PostgreSQL database I have the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE slide_results (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    tags character varying[] DEFAULT '{}'::character varying[]
);

INSERT INTO slide_results (id, tags)
    VALUES (1, '{Food, Housing}');

INSERT INTO slide_results (id, tags)
    VALUES (2, '{Security, Transport}');
```

Now I want to have sql query that will return one additional column, this column name is `domain_name`. Value of this column depends on what `tags` column have. If `tags` column have `Food` value then `domain_name` should be `I need food help`, if tags include `Transport` then `domain_name` will have `Transport help needed`. So result of the query should be

```
id             | domain_name
1              | I need food help
2              | Transport help needed
```

How can I do something like this in PostgreSQL?

Here is sql fiddle with db schema:

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pP7ZfNzVnisSG6xCjejqkY/0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT id,CASE WHEN 'Food' = ANY(tags) THEN 'I need food help'
               WHEN 'Transport' = ANY(tags) THEN 'Transport help needed' 
          END AS domain_name 
FROM slide_results;
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you need a table to convert `tag` to `domain_name`, e.g.

```
create table tag_domain(tag text, domain_name text);
insert into tag_domain values
('Food', 'I need food help'),
('Transport', 'Transport help needed');
```

and use it in this way:

```
select * 
from slide_results s
join tag_domain t on t.tag = any(s.tags)
```

[Db-Fiddle.](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pP7ZfNzVnisSG6xCjejqkY/1)